# count of a column in the result set on which distinct is already applied

Tags: sql

Consider the table `Property`.

```
KeyIdNum|Property|IdNum
1         12      1234
1         12      1234      
1         44      1234
1         12      1234
1         56      1234
2         12      4567
3         12      6789
3         56      6789
3         12      6789
4         44      3434
5         12      4444
6         44      9999
6         44      9999
```

It contains property num associated with each id num.But it contains duplicates.
I applied `distinct` to avoid duplicates.

```
select distinct KeyIdNum,Property,IdNum from Property.
```

So i got the result as :

```
KeyIdNum |Property |IdNum
1         12          1234
1         44          1234
1         56          1234
2         12          4567
3         12          6789
3         56          6789
4         44          3434
5         12          4444
6         44          9999
```

But now I want to `select( after applying distinct) ,the KeyIdNum (or IdNum) which are coming more than one time in the distinct result set shown above.
Please help me on this.I am not able to find a way to get the count of a column in the distinct result set using a single query.

Comment: expected out put should be

Comment: Thanks for editing my question in a proper format.Could you please let me know,how to provide questions in this format?

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Feel free to add one of them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select KeyIdNum,count(KeyIdNum) as count
From (
select distinct KeyIdNum,Property,IdNum from Table19 )A
 group by KeyIdNum
```

output

```
KeyIdNum    count
1           3
2           1
3           2
4           1
5           1
6           1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Below query will result of KeyidNum , its number of row count.

```html
select KeyIdNum,count(KeyIdNum)
From (
select distinct KeyIdNum,Property,IdNum from Property )
 group by KeyIdNum
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer.But when I tried with the same exact query , I got an error as "derived table expression is missing a correlation name" .but when I gave a name after the select query in from clause,the problem solved.Thank you very much for the reply

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses t-sql:

```
SELECT  x
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    rn = rownumber() OVER ( PARTITION BY keyidnum, idnum 
                                            ORDER BY keyidnum, idnum )
          FROM      tblProperty
        ) x
WHERE   rn > 1
```